# Error with prepare() function php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was testing to login with my script when I get an error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in/CMS/index.php on line 30

I check the 30th line and arround the 30th but i don't see where is the error :

```
    $userp = $sql->prepare("SELECT user, passwd FROM users WHERE user = :username AND passwd = :password LIMIT 1");
    $userp->execute(array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $passwd
        ));
```

The error was i didn't declare $sql variable. Mea culpa.

Comment: Did you have a question, or were you just giving a report on the current status of your development efforts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and make sure $sql is being created as a PDO instance BEFORE running the query. If the connection fails, then $sql will be null... a good way to check is this:

```
$sql = null;
try {
    $sql = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if($sql instanceof PDO)
{
     $userp = $sql->prepare("SELECT user, passwd FROM users WHERE user = :username AND             passwd = :password LIMIT 1");
     $userp->execute(array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $passwd
    ));
}
else
{
     // $Sql is null, and not an instance of PDO
}
```